# Cannot add objects to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Hi guys i'm trying a bit Swift and Parse, maybe you can tip me here, i don't know why my NSMutableArray typeAccessory is always empty, without objects, i'm trying to add objects from Parse.

[EDIT]

Im trying to do a Selector Action Sheet using XLForm, the Action Sheet needs an array of elements, i want to pass the objects from parse to the "row.selectorOptions " as an array.

//XLForm

```
row = XLFormRowDescriptor(tag :Tags.ActionSheet.rawValue, rowType:XLFormRowDescriptorTypeSelectorActionSheet, title:"Sheet")
        row.selectorOptions = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4", "Option 5"]
        row.value = "Option 3"
        section.addFormRow(row)
```

Any idea?

Thank you

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "submit:")
            self.loadAccessoryType() //loading function
    }    

    func loadAccessoryType()-> NSMutableArray{
         var typeAccessory:NSMutableArray? = NSMutableArray()
         var query = PFQuery(className:"accessory_type")
         query.selectKeys(["type"])
         query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
             (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                   if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                        for object in objects{
                            typeAccessory?.addObject(object["type"]!)
                         }
                      }
                   }else{
                        println("No results")
                   }
               }
            return typeAccessory!
}
```

Comment: where do you want the typeAccessory data to go? A table view? Provide context.

Comment: @BaseZen the data is going to fill a Selector Action Sheet using XLForm

Comment: One small tip... You don't need `NSMutableArray` in Swift. Just use a regular Swift array. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` will work asynchronously, so the method will ,,skip'' this block of code and go straight to `return typeAccessory` which will be always an empty array. Consider using `findObjects` method or if you insist on doing it asynchronously try using callbacks:

```
func loadAccessoryType(){
     var typeAccessory : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
     var query = PFQuery(className:"accessory_type")
     query.selectKeys(["type"])
     query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
         (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
               if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    for object in objects{
                        typeAccessory.addObject(object["type"]!)
                     }
                    self.onAddingObjectsCompleted(typeAccessory)
                  }
               }else{
                    self.onAddingObjectsFailed()
               }
           }

func onAddingObjectsCompleted(data : NSMutableArray) { 
//stuff to do when its done
}

func onAddingObjectsFailed() { 
//stuff to do when it failed
}
```

Comment: This help, a lot i will say, thank you @FruitAddict, but i still have "the same issue", i can print the array elements but just inside any function that i have, but not where i need it!

There is a function func initializeForm(){ ... } inside this function i need to pass the array with my new elements like this: row.selectorOptions = self. typeAccessory

But inside initializeForm the array is always empty.

The initializeForm() is always initialised into  override func viewDidLoad() {  initializeForm() ; loadAccessoryType}

Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
var typeAccessory:NSMutableArray = []
```

instead of

```
var typeAccessory:NSMutableArray? = NSMutableArray()
```

which will make an empty array,  and as on comment context is not clear!

To add object use

```
typeAccessory.addObject(yourObject)
```

hope it will help you !